# Deterministic hashing of Python 3 strings with adler32

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, zlib

I read [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/zlib.html) the following:

> **Note:**
>   To generate the same numeric value across all Python versions and
>   platforms use `adler32(data) & 0xffffffff`.

I am hoping to apply this to a string of the form: `"S89234IX"`, but when I do so, I get:

```
> zlib.adler32("S89234IX")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-84eee14d45ae> in <module>()
----> 1 zlib.adler32(campaigns_to_work_with[0])

TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Any thoughts on how to apply this function to a string?

Comment: Try `"S89234IX".encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data` must be a byte string. If you want to compute a checksum of Unicode data, you will need to encode it to a byte string, and you will need to make sure to stick with a specific encoding. For example, using UTF-8:

```
checksum = zlib.adler32("S89234IX".encode('utf-8')) & 0xffffffff
```